# Ejabberd installation failed to create cookie file in h: on Windows 10

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

In the past there was an older installation of ejabberd which worked on this machine, but after replacing it with a newer version (17.04), the installation throws an error as the post installation script fails. This is the error encountered by the post installation script -  "Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Failed to create cookie file 'h:/."

Comment: Can you please post the complete error message?

Comment: Specifically, the error message should say something like `Failed to create cookie file 'h:/.erlang.cookie': efoobar`, where `efoobar` is the reason for the error. My guess is that it says `eperm`, meaning that the application doesn't have write permission for `h:/.erlang.cookie`.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, this solved my issue from Command Prompt run as administrator.

```
cd C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.6\sbin

C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin> SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin> rabbitmq-service remove
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin> rabbitmq-service install
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin> rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin> net start RabbitMQ
```